# jquery / asp.net - get the number of images in a folder where the first two characters of the file name are XX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have been looking for the best way to obtain the total number images in a folder where the first two characters on the file name are XX and place this number into a variable.

So for example - I have a folder containing the following images:

XX-01.jpg
XX-02.jpg
XX-03.jpg
YY-01.jpg
ZZ-01.jpg

So I would populate the variable with 3 in this case.

Does anyone know of any way to do this?

Comment: I think there is no "Javascript/jQuery only" solution for your problem. You need some server-sided script (PHP) that reads out the folder and files.

Comment: In that case, I'll need to use asp.net (vb.net). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Do not do it in jQuery.

Go server side instead. Those are the kind of bad code another developer will curse you for.

Comment: Trouble is, the images I want to count will depend on a client side click - so if they click on button X, then count images X - or if they click on button Y, then count images Y. Does that make sense?? Doing it server side means I'd have to store the total of every different category (X, Y, Z, etc)

Comment: So, just pass an appropriate parameter with your call to server side. On the server side you could cache results for different values of that parameter.